# Accessing Spring Filter/HandlerInterceptor Multipart Parts and Parameters(form fields)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I am writing a Filter (also tried a HandlerInterceptor) and need to access the various parts of a MultiPart message - including Parameters (the form fields) and Files.  The sample code below only gives me Headers and general request information, returning null for any body/content request e.g. getParameter or getPart.

```
public class SampleFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterchain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

        log.info(request.getContentType());  //Works OK
        log.info(request.getHeader("X-Some-Header"));  //Works OK
        log.info(String.valueOf(request.getContentLength()));  //Works OK
        log.info(request.getParameter("some-form-field"));  //Does NOT work

        for (Part p : request.getParts())  //Does NOT work
        {
            log.info("Part:" + p.getName()); 
        }
}
```

I have created a HandlerInterceptor version of this, as I believe this happens later in the pipeline after the DespatcherServlet has processed the multi-part structure. This has enabled me to get the form fields/'parameters' from the request, but still no luck with the file parts.

```
public class SampleHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public boolean preHandle (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp, Object handler) throws Exception {

            log.info(request.getContentType());
            log.info(request.getHeader("X-sample-header"));
            log.info(String.valueOf(request.getContentLength()));

            for (String msg : request.getParameterValues("sample-field"))
            {
                log.info(msg);
            }

            log.info(String.valueOf(request.getParts().size()));  // Shows 0

            for (Part p : request.getParts())
            {
                log.info("Part:" + p.getName());
            }

            return true;
```

Most examples I've found so far talk about multipart within a normal controller (see below, I already have this) - I am specifically looking for either a Filter or HandlerInterceptor or similar pre-controller hook.

I have an existing RestController implementing MultiPart functionality successfully, however not sure how to apply this or a similar method to the Filter:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping (value = {"/**"})
@Slf4j
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/**"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> SampleMultipartController(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> httpheaders,
                                                        @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
                                                        @RequestParam("param2") List<String> param2,
                                                        @RequestParam ("file") List<MultipartFile> files) throws IOException {

//etc...
```

And I have a Commons multipartResolver defined:

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        final int MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = (100 * 1024 * 1024);
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE + MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE/5);
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE);
        multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE/100);
        return multipartResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved the problem by using a `HandlerInterceptor` (as this is post DespatcherServlet it seems the Multipart Resolver has been applied whereas it wasn't with the Filter), **and** by removing the Commons Multipart stuff and using the `@MultipartConfig` annotation instead.

```
@MultipartConfig
public class SampleHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp, Object handler) throws Exception {
```

The parts/form data can be accessed:

```
request.getParameter("some-form-field"))
```

or if multiple:

```
for (String val : request.getParameterValues("some-form-field"))...etc
```

and for the files:

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest req = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
req.getFile("some-file"))...etc...
```

or if multiple:

```
MultipartHttpServletRequest req = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
for (MultipartFile file : req.getFiles("some-file"))...etc...
```

Perhaps there are more elegant ways, but this worked.